# Using Unity over Java for building AR application with Tango

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, google-project-tango

I am planning to build an augmented reality app using Tango. It will allow to add virtual objects into real scenes. Should I go with Unity or Java or C?

Is Unity capable building AR applications with Tango and can it use Area Learning and depth features in Unity App?

According to StackOverflow that are quite many bugs that happens when using Unity? Are they a big problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use unreal engine in c++, libgdx in java. They are great.

Answer (score 1):

I started with JAVA cause I was most familiar with that language but then switched to Unity as I found it to be more mature with Tango and easier to do stuff with AR.

Answer (score 0):

I also started with Java but realistically there is nothing as powerful and simple as Unity available on the Tango platform for 3D content and gaming style interactive development.

In addition, if you want to develop utility applications such as mapping, 3D scanning or those that are not content based then C++ might be a better alternative.

Java seems the least good option of the possibilities as it has no really well supported Scenegraph like Unity, whereas C++ can take advantage of the many open source tools that can do interesting things with 3D.